# set absolute to a div in td

Tags: html, html-table, microsoft-edge

I have a div called "divOverlay" where it will show out when user hover the row. So I need it to be set as absolute inside a td. Currently it works in the Chrome but when I view it in the Edge, it is at the outside of td as shown as below which is not what I want. I want the button target stay inside the td:
[image]

Is there anyway that I can make it work for both chrome and edge browser?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="transform:scale(1);">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td><div class="divOverlay" style=" top: 0px; width: 58px; text-align: right; right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 25px; position: absolute; z-index: 1000;"><button title="Update" class="btn btn-success btn-xs amenddocbtn" type="button">TARGET</button></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i open the snippet in edge and work. are you sure you don't have any external css override css rule?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `transform: scale(1)` on the `tr` which contains the `button` element and it will work.

From this reference

> If the property has a value different than none, a stacking context will be created. In that case, the element will act as a containing block for any position: fixed; or position: absolute; elements that it contains.

[Stacking Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) will be created and due to that, it's not working as you expected.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.divOverlay {
  top: 0;
  width: 58px;
  text-align: right;
  right: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>
      <div class="divOverlay">
        <button title="Update" class="btn btn-success btn-xs amenddocbtn" type="button">TARGET</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..what i want to achieve is the button stay inside the td

Answer (score 0):

I try to test the issue and it looks like you are having this issue in the **MS Edge legacy** browser.

I found that `top: 0px;` and `position: absolute;` that you had added in the inline style for the DIV causing this issue in the **MS Edge legacy** browser.

the issue can be fixed by removing the `top: 0px;` and `position: absolute;` from the inline style of the DIV.

Modified code of the DIV:

```
<div class="divOverlay" style="width: 58px; text-align: right; right: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 25px; z-index: 1000;">
<button title="Update" class="btn btn-success btn-xs amenddocbtn" type="button">TARGET</button>
</div>
```

Output in the MS Edge legacy browser and Google Chrome browser:

[image]